# App not writing log statement to SDCard

Tags: android, logging, android-sdcard

I have written an app where i can send commands to a device via GCM (Push Notification). One command is START_LOGGING. When the device receives this command it should start writing log statements to a file on the SDCard. I have another command where i upload the file to my server.

I can use these mechanisms to remotely get bugs from a device. It works fine when i test it on my HTC One X running Android 4.2.2. I have tested it on a HTC Desire C running Android 4.0.3 and it is not logging the statements to the SDCard. It creates the file and i can upload it but the file is empty.

Any Ideas why? Thanks in advance.

```
public static void logToSdcard(Context context){

     String filename = context.getExternalFilesDir(null).getPath() + File.separator + "RR3.txt";
        String command = "logcat -f "+ filename + " -v time *:V -v time";

        Log.d(TAG, "command: " + command);

        try{
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        }
        catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Comment: Put a System.out.println() in the catch statement and see whether the IOException occurs

Comment: To run this on the phone, I think you have to give **adb logcat** instead of just logcat in the command

Comment: @Gautham No there is no exception being caught. So Should i try String command = "adb logcat -f "+ filename + " -v time *:V -v time";